# Get latest entry and join another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the username and timestamp of the most recent post where topicID is, for example, 88.

Users

```
id      |  username    
--------|----------
45234   | kaka   
32663   | lenny  
52366   | bob
```

Posts

```
id      |  message  | topicID | timestamp | userID
--------|-----------|---------|-----------|-------
675     | hello     | 88      | 100       | 32663
676     | hey       | 88      | 200       | 45234
677     | howdy     | 88      | 300       | 52366
```

So here I would want postID 677 and user bob.

Can I do this in a single sql query?

Would be great if I could implent it into this:

```
SELECT topics.id, topics.subject, topics.forum_id
FROM topics WHERE topics.forumID = 16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that table `Topic` is linked with table `Post` by `Topic.ID = Post.TopicID` and you want to get the latest `post` associated with it, you can have a subquery which basically gets the latest `id` (*assuming it's set as auto-incremented column*) for each `topicID` and join the result on table `Post` to get the other columns. Also you need to join on table `User` in order to get the name of the user who posted the entry.

```
SELECT  a.id, 
        a.subject, 
        a.forumid,
        b.message,
        b.timestamp,
        d.username
FROM    topic a
        INNER JOIN Posts b
            ON a.id = b.topicID 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  topicID, MAX(id) id
            FROM    Posts
            GROUP   BY topicID
        ) c ON b.topicID = c.topicID AND
                b.id = c.ID
        INNER JOIN users d
            ON b.userID = d.id
WHERE   a.forumID = 16
```

if you remove the `WHERE` clause, you will get all the latest entry for each `forumID`.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9339e/3)

Comment: Awesome. Just awesome. I love you!

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but off the top of my head, I think the following query will get you what you want:

```
SELECT Users.username, Posts.timestamp
FROM Users JOIN Posts on Users.id = Posts.userID
WHERE Posts.topicID = 88
ORDER BY Posts.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```